# Future Of NAV and AX

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-nav

May not be the correct forum but do you guys have any news regarding the future of MS NAV and AX.

I have heard(from AX Veterans) that Microsoft will stop support of AX and NAV by 2020. They are going to replace it with Office 365 based new ERP.

If this question should not be here then I apologize in advance but I am worried about our future hence the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong forum, but I'll answer anyway.

AX is not going anywhere right now and if anyone says otherwise they're wrong. What you're probably hearing is [Microsoft is ending support of the 2012 version in 2021](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/?p1=17873)...that's because they have a newer version out. It's equivalent to ending support of Windows 7 because we're on Windows 10 now.

These are the main active versions of AX in order (gotta love their naming conventions):

- AX 4.0 (Support has ended)
- AX 2009 (Support ends 2018)
- AX 2012 (Support ends 2021)
- Dynamics 365 **for Operations**

Dynamics 365 for Operations (aka D365fo aka D3fo) is the latest version and Microsoft is putting tons of weight and development into it. The core of it is still developed in X++. I also predict it will be the last version of AX and support will not end.

Dynamics NAV however I know very little on, but I believe NAV is being replaced with Dynamics 365 **for Financials**, which was formerly called "Project Madera", which was based on NAV. I could be wrong here and maybe D365 for Financial is the cloud version and NAV is the on-prem version. I don't know honestly.

Comment: Microsoft has not said anything about closing NAV on-prem or replacing it with a cloud based version. Right now Microsoft are developing NAV as they have been the past couple of years with a yearly major release. D365 for Financials is their own cloud based version of the public on-prem solution.

Comment: Got it, so NAV & D365 for Financials are just being developed in parallel right now. I would lean towards them ending NAV at some point though for potentially the 100% cloud offering.

Comment: NAV and D365 for Financials are different products. They may merge in the future, but at this stage are separate and running parallel.